# Поиск совпадений клеток

Tags: графы

Я не когда ещё не делал поиска кратчайшего пути и тому подобное и решить самостоятельное мне пока очень трудно, по этому я к Вам за советом.
Цель - определить все схожие по цвету клетки.
Немного погуглив я наткнулся на графы и на сколько я понял, мне как раз они и нужны.
Но даже поняв что мне нужно, мне сложно сделать первый рывок, посоветуйте мне что нибудь, что облегчит начала познавания.

[image]

Конечная цель такая - нажав на красный квадрат, выявить все красные квадраты, которые образуют непрерывный путь.Далее я должен удалить их и в появившуюся пустоту опустить зеленые квадраты.
Самое сложно для меня на данный момент - старт. Я не понимаю как нужно строить графы и как их заносить в массив и какими свойствами наделять сами графы(ячейки).

Comment: Уточните, что такое «схожие» по цвету? Зависит ли «схожесть» от расстояния между клетками? От разности значений цвета? Или цвет должен быть в точности одинаков? Что делать, если у нас есть цепочка цветов, плавно переходящая от одного цвета к другому (типа градиента)?

Comment: Схожие по цвету - одинакового цвета.
Я сейчас сижу читаю статьи, но мне намного всегда легче, когда я понимаю что делаю. Вот на сейчас, я даже не знаю с чего начать. Как нужно строить поле для квадратиков? Есть ли какая то определённая последовательность для этого? Сейчас ещё в вопрос допишу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если схожие == одинаковые, проблем вообще нету. просто обойдите все клетки таблицы.

На C#:

```
var cellDistribution = new Dictionary<Color, List<Cell>>();
foreach (var cell in Cells)
{
    var color = cell.Color;
    if (!cellDistribution.ContainsKey(color))
        cellDistribution.Add(color, new List<Cell>());
    colorToCells[color].Add(cell);
}

foreach (var colorAndList in cellDistribution)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Color: {0}", colorAndList.Key);
    Console.WriteLine("    Cells:");
    foreach (var cell in colorAndList.Value)
        Console.WriteLine("    [{0}, {1}]", cell.X, cell.Y);
}
```

Поле для квадратиков например, двумерный массив: `List<List<Cell>>`.

---

Окей, если вам нужны лишь квадраты одного цвета, образующие *непрерывный путь*, вам нужен Flood Fill.

Например, так:

```
struct Position
{
   public int x, y;
   public Position(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}

HashSet<Position> plannedTasks = new HashSet<Position>();
HashSet<Position> executedTasks = new HashSet<Position>();

plannedTasks.Add(new Position(clickedX, clickedY));

while (!plannedTasks.Empty())
{
    var task = plannedTasks.First();
    plannedTasks.Remove(task);
    Process(task);
    executedTasks.Add(task);
}

List<Position> collectedArea = new List<Position>();

void Process(Position p)
{
    if (Cells[p.x][p.y].Color != targetColor)
        return;
    collectedArea.Add(p);
    CheckAndAddTask(p.x - 1, p.y);
    CheckAndAddTask(p.x + 1, p.y);
    CheckAndAddTask(p.x, p.y - 1);
    CheckAndAddTask(p.x, p.y + 1);
}

void CheckAndAddTask(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < minX || y < minY || x > maxX || y > maxY)
        return;

    Position p = new Position(x, y);
    if (executedTasks.Contains(p))
        return;

    plannedTasks.Add(p);
}
```

Кстати: если в `plannedTasks` заменить `HashSet` на `Queue`, получится breadth-first search (поиск в ширину), а если на `Stack` — то depth-first search (в глубину). Обычно вместо `executedTasks` используют маркировку в `Cell` (выделяют специальное однобитовое поле, которое служит признаком «посещённости» этой клетки).